# Nginx Reserve Proxy Redirect Header

Tags: nginx

So the problem is happen to just one http://example.com/login , the other is work properly.
everytime my site http://abcd.com/login is always redirect to http://example.com/.
I try to curl -I http://abcd.com/login and this is what i got:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 06 Oct 2020 08:39:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: http://example.com
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImF4cXZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I try sub_filter but not working at this page, any solution??
this is my conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        sub_filter_once off;
        sub_filter_types text/css text/html text/javascript application/java;
        sub_filter 'example.com' 'abcd.com';
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: please find error log and send error $ sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 error is locatation cleared in line error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

Comment: configure the backend server on example.com with the correct baseurl of abcd,com.

Comment: can i make it work without touch the backend?

Comment: This is a redirect, use `proxy_redirect`, for example `proxy_redirect http://example.com http://whatever;` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

Comment: still not working, this problem is happen in just 1 page which is http://example.com/login

Comment: This redirect looks like it came from Laravel, not from nginx. Check your web application.

Comment: how to intercept it first, so it will not redirect to example.com but to abcd.com ?